# cant access files in s3 using pyspark code running in pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a basic pyspark code where I am trying to access s3 files from my pyspark code

The code is below, here I am reading a CSV file from my buckets. Its been a while but I keep getting the below error , although when I use boto I can do the same thing. Please suggest how can I fix this. I don't want to use boto3 bc it defeats my purpose of using spark

```
from pyspark.sql import *


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()


spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", \
                                     "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider,com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key","mykey")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key","mykey")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")


data = "s3a://atharv-test/huditest.csv"

authorsDf = spark.read.format('csv').option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(data)

authorsDf.show()
```

ERROR

---

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:893)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:869)

---

Comment: which jar are you using to connect the s3?

Comment: @JonathanLam. following are the jar names :  1.) aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.318 , 2.). aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.318 , 3.)hadoop-aws-3.3.0  4.) aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.318. 5.) aws-java-sdk-1.12.318.

Comment: If you notice they all are same version and I have put them in jars folder in spark directory. I am accessing it thru pycharm and given spark path in Enviornmental variables of pycharm IDE.